# Is there a name for polynomial roots that cannot be expressed in radicals?

Tags: galois-theory, radicals, irrational-numbers

It is known that there are polynomials of 5th degree or higher whose roots cannot be expressed as a finite combination (sum/product) of rationals and radicals.  These are not constructible numbers, but they differ from non-constructible numbers, such as the cube root of 2, which can be expressed with radicals.  I am wondering if there is a name for such numbers.  Maybe Galois numbers?

Comment: If there isn't an official name for these things, I propose the term “[Abel-Ruffini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) numbers”.

Comment: Non-solvable or non-radical as you wish. ${}{}{}$

Comment: I like "Abel-Ruffini", but maybe that is a bit long.  How about "AbRu" numbers?

Comment: "irradical numbers"?